# Setting up Dockerised command line application on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, command-line, alias

I am distributing command line application to Windows, OSX and Linux users. The application intended audience is developers, sysadmins and technically advanced users.

I am familiar how command line tools and Docker work on Unix. However I have not been using Microsoft Windows for development for over 10 years.

I want to make it so that when people type `app` from the command prompt or PowerShell, the docker entry point would be executed as it were a native command line application. However I do not know what is the best way to set this up for Windows users: should I somehow create a dummy EXE in PATH, acan I somehow alias Docker launch or does Docker for Windows itself provide some tools to run images easily without complicated setup and config file process.

To complicate matters futher, for `app` I am need to dome some virtual volume mappings, so that it can read and write files from the host drive e.g. it can process whatever input files are given for it. It will also communicate with localhost or  external HTTP servers already running on Windows.

What are the best practices how to make a smooth install process for `app`, so that I save the user from long command line commands or complicated configuration process and command would be available in their default command line session?

Can I give the users one liner command that would set up the `app` and Docker image for them?

Here is the earlier question how do I create the Docker image:

[Containerising Python command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449347/containerising-python-command-line-application/53450791#53450791)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I somehow create a dummy EXE in PATH

- Create a wrapper *batch file* (`*.cmd`) - which both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell are capable of invoking just like binary executables - and place it in one of the directories listed in `%PATH%`.

  - There is no standardized directory on Windows, however (whereas Linux has `/usr/bin` and macOS `/usr/local/bin`), so your setup procedure may have to create one and use `setx.exe` to persistently add it to the `%PATH%`.
- Make the wrapper batch file perform setup on demand and then invoke the target Docker image, passing all arguments (`.*`) through.

> Can I give the users one liner command that would set up the app and Docker image for them?

You can craft a lengthy PowerShell command that does all of the above, or use a simpler bootstrapping command for downloading and executing an installation script stored online.

---

Sample wrapper batch file `app.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set appName="%~n0"

:: #  perform on-demand configuration...

:: # Invoke the application in the target container.
sudo docker run -it %appName%:0.1 %appName%.py %*
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in a near-universal scripting language (Python); your user target is developers and sysadmins (who are likely to already have Python installed); and a key part of your application is interacting with non-Docker host files and other services; then you're probably not looking for a Docker container.  The application should be directly runnable on the host.

Python already has [a fairly robust packaging system](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and I'd lean on that as your primary distribution mechanism.  A technically skilled user won't be scared of

```sh
python -m venv $HOME/myapp
. $HOME/myapp/activate
pip install myapp
```

(Remember that native Docker for Linux requires root permission to do anything; and Docker for Mac/Windows can only access some files, generally "near" the user's home directory; contacting the host and managing file permissions are both perennial sources of trickiness for processes that are really about working with the host but for whatever reason run in Docker.)